# Blocking among HTTP Web Service threads when performing XML validation using javax.xml.validation.Validator

Tags: java, xml, schema, validation

My simple web service receives a Zip file of an XML document and I try to validate the XML with a XSD schema file. Below is the code snippet

```
        Schema schema = BlahSchemaFactory.newSchema("Blah.xsd");
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        BlahErrorHandler eh = new BlahErrorHandler();
        validator.setErrorHandler(eh);

        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipFileContentAsBytes));
        zis.getNextEntry(); 

        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(zis);
        validator.validate(xmlSource);
```

The **BlahSchemaFactory** is a singleton and helps create the Schema object only once per passed XSD file. Now, the problem arises when several HTTP threads are passing thru code above. They are blocking one another deep in the code of validate() method.

Following is the stack trace as obtained from the HP Diagnostic tools.

```
    "blah_thread_77" Id=472 in BLOCKED on lock=org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression@3c9d97f9
         owned by d1_thread_237 Id=21648
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.matches(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.matches(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl.getActualValue(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:124)
        at BlahPackage.BlahClass.uploadSaveFileRecord(BlahRecord.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:111)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
```

**Question:** Is there any way I can avoid the blocking on the threads ? Please suggest !

Comment: Since newSchema() doesn't really return a new schema, what about newValidator?  Are you using the same instance for multiple threads?

Comment: @SteveH. : I want to believe that the call I am making, schema.newValidator() is actually giving me new Validator for every HTTP thread running thru the code. Otherwise based on Valildator spec, I am sure to run into thread-safety issues.

Comment: I would try loading separate instances of the schema and see what happens.  Don't use the SchemaFactory, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet that resolves the thread-blocking issue when trying to validate a XML using a XSD schema. You need to :

1. Make sure you create a new Schema per thread
2. Make sure when calling newSchema on SchemaFactory synchronize the
   call (as shown)
3. Instead of calling
   BlahObject.class.getClassLoader().getResource(schemaFileOnClassPath)
   use Singleton of some sort to get the URL of the XSD only once, otherwise you would run into thread blocking where class loader is attempting to find the
   resource (this was identified using HP Diagnostic Tool)

   ```
       SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
       URL schemaURL = BlahSchemaSingleton.getSchemaURL("Blah.xsd");
       Schema schema = null; 

       synchronized(schemaFactory) {
           schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaURL);
       }

       Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
       BlahErrorHandler eh = new BlahErrorHandler();
       validator.setErrorHandler(eh);

       ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipFileContentAsBytes));
       zis.getNextEntry(); 

       Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(zis);
       validator.validate(xmlSource);
   ```